# Does X-Ray Diffractometry actually involve diffraction?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, x-ray-crystallography

To my understanding, diffraction is the bending of waves as they pass by edges or go through slits. However, I cannot find a description of x-ray diffractometry that actually involves diffraction. All I find is Bragg's law, which describes reflections. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've always considered Diffraction as a general term that describes all the situations in which EM waves suffer a change in the direction of propagation. Hence reflection, refraction, diffusion... are all, in a sense, a 'diffraction'.

Comment: It may help to see the classroom demo in which you compare the pattern generated by directing a laser through a single slit with that generated by directing a laser at a similarly sized barrier. They generate photon-negative images of one another and you use the math of diffraction to describe both.

Comment: But there quite distinct differences between the different ways light can change direction. Reflection for example is brought about when an EM wave is redirected by a charged particle acting as an "antenna." But diffraction is again, the bending of a wave around barriers. I suppose in a non-rigorous sense they could be used interchangeably, but I'm trying to understand the specifics of this process.

Comment: dmckee, the two situations you just described both use the math of diffraction because they are both examples of diffraction.

Comment: Good. Now: while the central maxima of your XRD pattern will be in a geometry consistent with reflection off of various planes, each plane also creates  other orders which are *not* in such a geometry. How does that happen? Diffraction. And more: the fact that the central maxima are in reflection geometry is a result of the diffractive math (this is guaranteed because reflection also is a consequence of Huygens' principle: it's a special case of diffraction).